# Open GL2.0 library codes

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, opengl-2.0

So my teacher has given us the following two pieces of code

```
gl.glMatrixMode(5889);
```

and

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
```

I know these two are the same, but I was wondering where I can get a list of these codes for GL2 ? Prefer to use the enum instead of hard coded values so I know what I am doing, but some of our work doesn't have this information.

Comment: Pop open [`gl.h`/`glext.h`/`glcorearb.h`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php) & search for the hex value you want?

Comment: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/constant-values.html#com.jogamp.opengl.fixedfunc.GLMatrixFunc.GL_PROJECTION

Comment: That's a very bad and dangerous behaviour. It drammatically decreases code readability and makes your code error prone

Comment: I'm not sure why your teacher would even teach you this!?